# QScrollarea Stylesheet with QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet, qwidget, qscrollarea

I have a problem with the inheritance system of the parent-child Css while I tried all possibilities with the Id Selector in the Css.
the QScrollarea contains a QWidget type model with the following hierarchy:

Qt hierarchy class

[image]

I do not understand even though I change the QWidget (modelWidget) to QFrame, it does not change anything. here is the Css code:

```
QScrollArea#PreviewModel{
    background-color: #282828;
    border: none;
}

QWidget#WidgetContents{
    background-color: #282828;
}

QWidget#modelWidget{
    border: 2px solid #00aaff;
}
```

Here is what shows me:

Result Css 1

[image]

and if I remove the css #WidgetContents it gives me here:

```
QScrollArea#PreviewModel{
    background-color: #282828;
    border: none;
}

#modelWidget{
    border: 2px solid #00aaff;
}
```

result:

Result Css 2

[image]

the content of modelWidget still influenced by the WidgetContents
a little help please?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html)? If you want a help with debugging QSS you should provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *modelWidget* is a child of *WidgetContents*, so it will inherit its CSS `background-color: #282828;` and give the first screenshot. When you remove the CSS of WidgetContents you no longer inherit it. Indeed it seems that the QWidget is not inheriting from the QScrollArea. What is your question ?

Comment: the question is,  im using the ID Selector for the QWidget (WidgetContents) so that mean the id Matches all QWidget instances whose object name is WidgetContents. and the problem i have only one object with this name. so he must apply the css only on WidgetContents not his childs.